# How do I make clients understand that I am the right freelancer for my assignment?

Tags: difficult-client, portfolio, proposal

Thank you for your help.

I tried to get a job at [freelancer.com](https://www.freelancer.com/).
I have regular mark and more than 20 cases of contracts.
I proposed to a work to create website using React.
The client sent a message to me. I thought that he was interested in my skills.
He said that my portfolio is good, but then he wanted to see my projects.
I have done 3 projects but all of them had Nondisclosure Agreements.
I explained about it.
But the client didn't believe me and said that my career is **lie**.
But it wasn't lie.
Then he declined my proposal.
I wanted to work with him and I can. But I cannot get the job.
What to do then?

Comment: Why the close vote? It seems a reasonable question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even if you are 100% honest and upfront, this person, for whatever reason, has a mindset about you that you will **not** overcome, especially online.

Regardless of whether or not you want to work on the project, he/she doesn't want to work with you. There's *nothing* you can do. Move on, find a different client.

In the mean time, you might want to start thinking about work you **can** show off. Even if that means creating projects that may not be "real world". You really need to have *something* a prospective client can see. work history may encourage a potential client to contact you... but only a portfolio of past work will convince a potential client to *hire* you.

---

Note that question directly related to working with, or the functionality of crowdsource freelance sites are off topic here. There shouldn't really be a need to link to a crowdsourcing site.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If I find this kind of job, what should I do?

Comment: I can't really explain how to get hired. I don't know you, your abilities, skills, experience.. etc. I would merely encourage you *not* to waste energy if a client has clearly expressed that they do not wish to work with you or if they've been unduly insulting.

Answer (score 2):

I assume the NDAs you have signed are terribly restrictive - so your prior clients owe you nothing.

Having said that, perhaps it could be worth a shot asking the clients if there are any details you are allowed to divulge. Depending on your relationship, they might accommodate you.

Moving forward, you could attempt to water down any NDA, making it possible for you to use at least some clients as partial references.